# Webots - Open multiple windows side by side

Tags: robotics, webots

I'd like to edit my proto files and my project files side by side in two different windows (I've a big screen / monitor). However seems like I can only create a "New world" which will open in the same window, and there is no "Window" menu either. Is it possible to have multiple webots world windows simultaneously open?

[image]

Thank you!

P.S. I use macOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to open several world files simultaneously in Webots. However, you can open several instances of Webots with different world files. But within the same instance of Webots you can edit as many PROTO files as you like. You should simply open them from the `File` menu, `Open Text File...`.

Comment: Hey, thanks Olivier for the answer. On mac, I believe the (only) way is through command line - "open -n /Applications/Webots.app/".